# react-qr-reader installation issue with REACT

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to install react-qr-reader from https://github.com/JodusNodus/react-qr-reader. I installed REACT and REACT dom just fine but after I added the react-qr-reader package I get this:

```
root@server [~]# npm install --save react-qr-reader
npm WARN react-qr-reader@2.0.1 requires a peer of react@^15.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-qr-reader@2.0.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN root@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN root@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

How can I identity the missing peer?
When I try and load the js script I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at that line: "import React, { Component } from 'react'". So I'm assuming PEAR is not even properly installed.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @monamona Post updated. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install react and react-dome

```
npm i react react-dom
```

Then try install react-qr-reader with `sudo` command

```
sudo npm i react-qr-reader --save
```

Answer (score -2):

```
npm i react-qr-reader --force
```

use This its definitely Work For You

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.